# How to insert new ordered nodes into a double linked list?

Tags: c

I am starting to program in c and I have a question. I have to do a job where I have to program a double link list. In this program I have to insert the nodes and order them by numbers (DNI) and then save it in a text file. I have tried several times, when I put a smaller number it doesn't save it in the list, but when I put the first number or a bigger number it adds it to me, but not in the correct order. Where am I wrong? How could I improve it? Thanks in advance.

```
struct data {
int dia;
int mes;
int any; };


struct Info {
char nom [30];
long int dni;
char correu [30];
struct data fecha;
char sexe; };

typedef struct nodo
{
  struct Info dato;
  struct nodo* sig;
  struct nodo* atras;
  int cantidadnotes;
  float notes [];
    }Nodo;

typedef Nodo *p_nodo;
typedef Nodo *Lista;

void Insertar(Lista *lista) {
 p_nodo nuevo, actual;
 long int dni;
 int i = 0, cantidad;
 float nota;
actual = *lista;
printf("Introdueix la cuantitat de notes que vols afegir al alumne: ");
scanf("%d",&cantidad);
nuevo = (p_nodo)malloc(sizeof(Nodo) + cantidad * sizeof(float));
if(nuevo==NULL)
{
    printf("Error en la memoria");
    return;
}
else
{
    printf("Escriu el nom complet: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", &nuevo->dato.nom[0]);
    printf("Escriu el teu correu: ");
    scanf("%s", &nuevo->dato.correu[0]);
    printf("Escriu el dni sense lletra: ");
    scanf("%ld", &dni);
    while (dni < 0 || dni > 99999999)
    {
        printf("Error amb el dni afegeix un altre: ");
        scanf("%ld", &dni);
    }
    while(actual)
    {
        while (actual->dato.dni == dni)
        {
            printf("Ja existeix el dni afegeix un altre: ");
            scanf("%ld", &dni);
        }
            actual = actual->sig;
    }
    nuevo->dato.dni = dni;
    printf("Escriu la data del teu cumpleanys (DD/MM/ANY): ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &nuevo->dato.fecha.dia, &nuevo->dato.fecha.mes, &nuevo->dato.fecha.any);
    printf("Escriu el teu genere: ");
    scanf(" %s", &nuevo->dato.sexe);
    while(i<cantidad)
    {
        printf("Nota: ");
        scanf("%f", &nota);
        if (nota >= 0 && nota <= 10)
        {
            nuevo->notes[i] = nota;
            i++;
        }
        else  printf("Error: \n");
    }
    nuevo->cantidadnotes = cantidad;
    actual = *lista;
    if(actual) while(actual->atras) actual = actual->atras;
    if(!actual || actual->dato.dni > dni)
    {
        nuevo->sig = actual;
        nuevo->atras = NULL;
        if(actual) actual->atras = nuevo;
        if(!*lista) *lista = nuevo;
    }
    else
    {
        while(actual->sig && actual->sig->dato.dni <= dni)
        {
            actual = actual->sig;
        }

        nuevo->sig = actual->sig;
        actual->sig = nuevo;
        nuevo->atras = actual;
        if(actual->sig) nuevo->sig->atras = nuevo;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Time to strap this into a debugger and see what's going on internally.

Comment: .. and stop hiding pointers behind typedefs ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in the code.

**Issue #1**

When you insert a DNI sequence of `3` and `2`, `2` will never be represented in the list. The insert takes place, but the new root-pointer is never assigned to `*lista`:

```
if(!*lista) *lista = nuevo;
```

It must be assigned unconditionally:

```
*lista = nuevo;
```

**Issue #2**

When you insert a DNI sequence of `2` and `3`, the code dereferences a NULL-pointer because `nuevo->sig` is NULL in that case (`sig` of the last node `actual` is NULL). This needs an additional condition:

```
if(actual->sig && nuevo->sig) nuevo->sig->atras = nuevo;
```

With those two adjustments, the ordered list works as expected with random input:

```
Lista list = NULL;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Insertar(&list);
}
while (list) {
    printf("%ld\n", list->dato.dni);
    list = list->sig;
}
```

```
171
208
214
337
648
670
745
754
818
993
```